# Apttus to mulesoft Integration

Tags: salesforce, mule, integration, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

Am trying to connect and fetch product/Item data from Apttus using mulesoft and send it to netsuite,I am not having much of information but I heard its part of salesforce so can I use salesforce connector to connect?,I have searched google but I didnt find any example to connect apptus to mulesoft.Can anyone help? if its part of sales force what operation should I choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Salesforce connector will integrate with Apttus only if you're using standard and supported functions of the **force.com** platform.

You should therefore be able to create custom objects, and retrieve or filter them through DataSense.